# How to make funcunit close the new browser window after tests

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, javascriptmvc, funcunit

I'm using funcunit for testing my JavascriptMVC application. It opens a new browser window where it runs my application. I wish it also closed the window after tests.

How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Call S.win.close() to close the window opened by funcunit . You can also access other stuff loaded in that like , accessing jQuery instance of that dom using S.win.$

Comment: With newer funcunit, this works: 
teardown: function() {
    F.win.close();
}

Answer (score 0):

Call:

```
FuncUnit._window.close();
```

It will close the opened window of the test.

```
module('General',{
    setup: function() {
        S.open('test.html');
    },
    teardown: function() {
        S._window.close();
    }
});

test('Test', function() {
    ok(true, 'I live again');
});
```

Comment: I added that in my teardown for the module, but I get "FuncUnit_window is not defined".

Comment: I think, you can use S._window as well. The _window is "private" property which actually contains the window.